# Proving the zero morphism absorbes composition in preadditive category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm trying to prove that in a preadditive category the representable functors Hom$(A,-)$ are additive. In order to do that I need to use that the zero morphisms (in the sense of being the zero element of the abelian group structure in the hom-set) absorbe composition but I don't see how to prove that.

Let $0 \in$ Hom$(A,B)$ be the zero of the group, $g \in$ Hom$(B,C)$ and $f \in$ Hom$(D,A)$ then I need to prove that given arbitrary morphisms $h \in$ Hom$(A,C)$ and $k \in$ Hom$(D,B)$ the following equalities hold:
$$h+(g0)=h$$ $$k+(0f)=k$$
Why is that true? I can't realize.
Note that I'm not assuming that the category has a zero object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in any abelian group, it is enough to find **one** element $y$ such that $x+y=y=y+x$ to prove that $x=0$. In particular, you can take $y=x$, so that the implication becomes $x+x=x\Rightarrow x=0$.

So in your case, it is enough to prove the identities for $h=(g0)$ and $k=(0f)$. In that case, you have
$$(g0)+(g0)=g(0+0)=g0\Rightarrow g0=0$$
and similarly
$$(0g)+(0g)=(0+0)g=0\Rightarrow 0g=0,$$
simply because composition is bilinear.

Note that this is the same as proving that $0$ is absorbant for any bilinear map; there is nothing specific about preadditive categories in this argument.